# Apollo client only returns { __typename: 'Typehere' } when fetchPolicy is not 'no-cache'

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a query that returns the sample data below

```
{ 
  __typename: 'Typehere',
  name: 'type',
  address: 'address type'
}
```

When I use `useQuery` with an option of fetchPolicy: 'cache-first' the GQL API returns the correct data. But when I use console.log(response), the data will now transform to

```
{ 
  __typename: 'Typehere'
}
```

Api call and response for fetchPolicy: 'cache-first'
[image]

console.log(response)
[image]

Why is this happening?

I tried fetching the data using fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' and works without issues, however, I need to cache it for optimization.
I've also tried other fetch policies stated in the apollo client docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it using `possibleTypes`

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {....}
  possibleTypes: {
    Typehere: ['Type1', 'Type2']
  }
});
```

Turns out that apollo client needs to know possible implementations of `Typehere`